# Shiny CSS selectors for withProgress() box

Tags: r, shiny, progress

In Shiny, I would like to enlarge my `withProgress()` box and move it front and center. In my app, the user shouldn't modify certain UI elements while stuff in the background is running. The problem is that I don't know the right CSS selectors to control the box. For example, when I try to add a thick red border, only the progress bar is affected.

```
.shiny-progress-container, .shiny-progress, .progress, .progress-bar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    border: 10px solid red;
}
```

Bonus if there's a way to forgo CSS altogether.